# CM server Sitecore 9 Update 1 is hosted on the Azure with XP Scaled didn't see the owin.initialize pipeline

Tags: azure, paas, owin

I have used the pipeline profile and found the **owin.initialize** pipeline isn't available on the CM server which is hosted on the Azure App service.

I have used the Sitecore 9 Update 1 - XP Scaled.
How can I turn on the **owin.initialize** pipeline on the CM server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After play around in the config files, I found there is a flag inside the web.config where contains the `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`. I changed it to true value then the owin.initialize pipeline turns on.

**Update**
I would like to share more details about this issue. Please remind that in the web.config already have a setting value:

`<add key="owin:appStartup" value="Sitecore.Owin.Startup, Sitecore.Owin" />`

This setting is a default value which turns on **owin.initialize** pipeline.
Setting the value **true** in the key `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` or remove the **owin:AutomaticAppStartup** out the web.config file also turn on the **owin.initialize** pipeline.